# Refactoring PHP-based IP-Filter to work with IPv6

Tags: php, ipv6, whitelist

I have an IP-Filter for a whitelist in one of my older projects, which I want to reuse in a new application.

edit for clarification; It works like this:

The whitelist contains entries in a format specified below. Using `foreach ($whitelist as $listed)`, I check which type the current entry (`$listed`) is, and then compare this entry with `$ip`. As soon as it finds an entry, that matches the specified IP, it will return true, if after going through the whole whitelist no match was found it will return false.

As of now, only IPv4 is supported and the filter allows for a whitelist entries like followed:

1. IP-range by specifying BEGIN - END (`192.168.0.1-192.168.0.5`)
2. single IP-address (e.g. `192.168.0.2`)
3. IP-range using a *-wildcard (e.g. `192.168.0.*`)

The methods to check each of these cases look like this, where `$ip` is the client's IP and `$listed` is an entry from the whitelist/blacklist matching one of the above mentioned formats:

```
public function checkAgainstRange($ip, $listed)
{
    list($begin, $end) = explode('-', $listed);
    $begin = ip2long($begin);
    $end = ip2long($end);
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
    return ($ip >= $begin && $ip <= $end);
}

public function checkAgainstSingle($ip, $listed)
{
    return long2ip(ip2long($ip)) === long2ip(ip2long($listed));
}

public function checkAgainstWildcard($ip, $listed)
{
    $listedSegment = explode('.', $listed);
    $ipSegment = explode('.', $ip);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($listedSegment); $i++) {
        // We're finished when the wildcarded block is reached
        // Important: Check for wildcard first, as it won't match the client IP!
        if ($listedSegment[$i] == '*') {
            return true;
        }
        if ($listedSegment[$i] != $ipSegment[$i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Just to be safe: If we reach this, something went wrong
    return false;
}
```

I need some directions as to how to make these work with IPv6-addresses.

Some of the required changes are obvious:
  * `ip2long()` only works with IPv4-addresses
  * I have to check for `:` as a possible delimiter in `checkAgainstWildcard()`.

I found `inet_ntop()`and `inet_pton()` in the php-docs. Can I just use the following to compare two single ip-addresses?

```
public function checkAgainstSingle($ip, $listed)
{
    $ip = inet_ntop($ip);
    $listed = inet_ntop($listed);
    if ($ip === false || $listed === false) {
        throw new \Exception;
    }
    return $ip === $false;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
$filter = new IpFilter();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$result = $filter->checkAgainstSingle($ip, '192.168.0.1');
$result = $filter->checkAgainstRange($ip, '192.168.0.1-192.168.0.10');
$result = $filter->checkAgainstWildcard($ip, '192.168.0.*');
```

Is it even useful to keep something like `checkAgainstRange()`? And if so, how could I even check for IPv6-ranges in a similar way? Obviously I cant't change `ip2long()` to `inet_ntop()` here...

Same goes for wildcard-ranges. Should I keep them and would it suffice to check for `:` as a segment delimiter and if it is not found, fall back to `.` as delimiter?

Comment: What exactly should the filter do? I don't get what the expected result is here. Could you provide some demo? Should the result be wether the given IP matches the given patern?

Comment: Yes, it is an Ip-filter matching an IP against a whitelist, by checking if `$ip == $filtered`, where `$filtered` is a single entry from the whitelist in one of the mentioned formats. Basically I loop through my whitelist and stop as soon as i find an entry which matches my ip. I will edit my question, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IP address in in human-readable/printable format then you can use inet_pton() to convert it to binary form. Then you can for example use bin2hex() to show the binary data in hexadecimal form.

Example:

```
$address = inet_pton("2a00:8640:1::1");
echo bin2hex($address);
```

will show you:

```
2a008640000100000000000000000001
```

If you then want to check on subnet instead of on separate address you can compare the first 16 hexadecimal characters. IPv6 subnets are almost always /64 networks, each hexadecimal character is 4 bits, so the first (64 / 4 =) 16 characters show you the subnet. Remember that with IPv6 a machine can have multiple IPv6 addresses and if it uses privacy extensions (enabled by default on recent Windows and Mac OS X systems) then it will change it's source address regularly. Matching on subnet might be the most useful for IPv6.